# My ee in not define?? I define it. In this if's in for loop

Tags: python, sql, if-statement, for-loop, cursor

I have a little problem with my Python program. They not define my "ee"!

My code of my problem

```
cursor = cnx.cursor()

read_ee = ("SELECT e_or_e FROM ITN "
           "WHERE name = 'names' ")
cursor.execute(read_ee)
for(e_or_e) in cursor:
  if(e_or_e == "exit"):
    ee = "enter"
  elif(e_or_e == "enter"):
    ee = "exit"

print("EE is ", ee)
```

And Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SQL3.py", line 43, in <module>
    print("EE is ", ee)
NameError: name 'ee' is not defined
```

Program is for reading and wraiting to my MySQL Database (MySQL server is on other computer but if i delete that fragment is all ok!)

Someone knows how to fix this? I was trying everything!

Comment: I would `print(cursor.fetchall())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the *if* or *elif* ever evaluate to *True* so it never gets defined:

```
for e_or_e  in cursor:
    if e_or_e == "exit": # always False
      ee = "enter"
    elif e_or_e == "enter": # always False
      ee = "exit"

print("EE is ", ee) # undefined
```

You can give it a default value before the loop:

```
ee = None
for e_or_e  in cursor:
   if e_or_e == "exit": 
      ee = "enter"
    elif e_or_e == "enter":
      ee = "exit"

 # if ee is not None we assigned some value in the loop
if ee is not None:
   print("EE is ", ee)
```

But if you are expecting one of your if/elif to be True then you may want to investigate why that is not happening.

Your code actually fails as you are comparing strings to tuples, what you can do is use in:

```
for e_or_e  in cursor:
   if "exit" in e_or_e: 
      ee = "enter"
      break
   elif "enter" in e_or_e:
      ee = "exit"
      break
else:
     # neither exit nor  enter are returned
```

Comment: I ask because i don't now why is always False i must define it! And if i want to print "e_or_e" it print me this "('E_OR_E is ', (u'exit',))" I just write "print("E_OR_E is ", e_or_e)" in for loop

Comment: You need e_e[0],  row is a tuple

Comment: No worries, I imagine you want to break when you find either value so I added how to solve the problem using `in` using break if you find the value

Comment: On a sidenote you could get the ee using IN directly with mysql

Answer (score 0):

If `e_or_e` does not equal neither to `"exit"`, nor to `"enter"`, then `ee` will never have a value.